# How to Access ScrollViewer of WPF WebBrowser Component

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

How can I reference and change the settings for the ScrollViewer of a WebBrowser component of a C#/WPF/XAML form from the backing C# code?

```
            <WebBrowser ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
                        ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
                        ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="False"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
                        Name="BrowserForm"  />
```

For example, the following isn't defined:

```
this.BrowserForm.ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility
```

I tried accessing the ScrollViewer from the VisualTreeHelper, but the following returns 0:

```
VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(this.BrowserForm, 0)
```

Comment: Are you sure that your attempts at accessing the ScrollViewer are occurring after the WebBrowser has been loaded?  For example... if you implemented the "Loaded" event of your WebBrowser... and put the code there... does it still not work?

Comment: It won't be defined because those are attached properties. Give me a second to make sure i have the right syntax, and I'll show you how to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That syntax doesn't work because you are setting an **attached property** ([MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms749011%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)).

To set it **in code**, you have to utilize the static method defined by the class defining the property, in this case `ScrollViewer.SetHorizontalScrollBarVisibility`

```
ScrollViewer.SetHorizontalScrollBarVisibility(MyBrowser, ScrollBarVisibility.Visible);
```

**Note:** `WebBrowser` does not appear to actually be affected by this property, in XAML or in code, but this concept *is* correct. You may want to try wrapping your `WebBrowser` inside of a `ScrollViewer` if you want more control over scrolling.

Comment: The `WebBrowser` control is not WPF-native but rather "internally instantiates the native WebBrowser ActiveX control" (from [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.webbrowser%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)) therefore there are a whole bunch of WPF features that it doesn't support (opacity, transforms, etc).

Comment: Also, those particular properties of `ScrollViewer` do not have to be set in code, setting them in XAML is perfectly valid (just not for the `WebBrowser` control due to reasons mentioned above). For example, if @George's control was a `ListBox` it would be fine to set the `ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility` attached property on that element in order to affect the inner `ScrollViewer` element. In fact, that is a good way of removing scroll bars from a list box without needing to change its control template.

Comment: @StevenRands agreed, I'll specify that the code I provided is for setting it *in code*. Of course the XAML method is also valid.